# How do I open same instance of view controller?

Tags: swift, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I am trying to open the same instance of a tableview each time I click on a tableview cell but all I get is a newly created view. For example, when I go to the "CounterViewController" and use the counter, when I go back to it later, the counter is back down to zero.

Here is the code I currently have for instantiating the view controller.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TimerViewController") as! TimerViewController
        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    if indexPath.row == 1 {
        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DateViewController") as! DateViewController
        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    if indexPath.row == 2 {
        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CounterViewController") as! CounterViewController
        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

I would like to note that I am using a navigation view controller and when I use this method, it also doesn't show the navigation bar at the top of the view controllers passed the tableview controller.

Let me know if there is any more information required to answer this question properly. Thank you.

Comment: You see what you see because that is the exact behavior you get from the code you wrote. You explicitly create a new view controller each time a row is tapped. You make no attempt to reuse a controller. And you present the new controller. This does not use the current navigation controller. Perhaps you should push instead of present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have pointed out, your code uses `instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:)` to CREATE A NEW INSTANCE of the view controller class each time you select a cell. You will, by definition, get a new cell every time by doing that.

Instead, create an array of `Optional` View controllers populated with `nil` and use that to fetch your desired view controller. If it exists, use it. If not, create it and save it in your array:

```
//Create an array of view controller identifiers to use to create VCs
let identifiers = ["TimerViewController", "DateViewController", "CounterViewController"]

//Create an array of [UIViewController?] and populate it with nil values
var viewControllers: [UIViewController?] = Array(repeating: nil, count: identifiers.count)
```

Then create a function to return a view controller for your index. Something like this:

```
func viewControllerAt(index: Int) -> UIViewController {
  guard index < viewControllers.count else {
    fatalError("index out of range!")
  }
  var result = viewControllers[index] //try to fetch a VC from the array

  //if it's nil, create a VC using the correct identifier and save it to the array
  if result == nil {
    result = InstantiateViewController(withIdentifier: identifiers[index]
    viewControllers[index] = result
  }
  return result
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
  let vc = viewControllerAt(indexPath.row)
  self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Note that I answered the "letter" of your question: How to display the same instance of a view controller each time you tap a cell.

As Matt pointed out, it might be better to create an array of state data, and create new instance of your view controllers on each tap like you are doing now, but populate the new child view controller with the saved state data for that row. This is so common that it has a name: The master/detail design pattern, and there is even system support for it. Try a search on the iOS master/detail design pattern for more information.

Comment: Telling the OP (and others) that it's somehow okay to retain a view controller that's no longer in the view hierarchy like that is just wrong.

Comment: @matt, It's not the conventional way of handling this problem, but tab bar controllers and page view controllers both do something quite similar.

Comment: So, for that matter, do navigation controllers.

Comment: Yes, I thought you might respond that way. :) But those are parent view controllers maintaining their children.

Comment: This seems rather like a parent/child relationship though. (although more like master/detail)